# Optimizing changing textures in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures

I'm trying to get random pictures from a folder and then use them as a texture on a wall that changes at a given interval. The code works, but there is a massive performance hit whenever `LoadImages()` is called, since it is in VR, it is very noticeable and makes the application unusable.

Is there a better way to change the textures to be less intense performance-wise?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PhotoViewer : MonoBehaviour
{

GameObject[] gameObj;
Texture2D[] textList;

string[] files;
string[] filesShort;
string pathPreFix;
public float refresh = 10.0f;
public float targetTime = 10.0f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    Debug.Log (targetTime);
    //Change this to change pictures folder
    Debug.Log(Application.dataPath);

    string path = @"" + Application.dataPath + "/Images";

    pathPreFix = @"file://";

    gameObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Pics");

    files = new string[gameObj.Length];

    files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (path, "*.jpg");
    //ShuffleArray(files);

    StartCoroutine (LoadImages ());
    //LoadImages ();
}


void FixedUpdate ()
{
    Debug.Log (targetTime);
    targetTime -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    if (targetTime <= 0.0f)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Update!");
        targetTime = refresh;
        LoadImages ();
        //Start();
    }
}

public static void ShuffleArray<T>(T[] arr)
{
    Debug.Log ("In Shuffle");
    for(int i = arr.Length - 1; i > 0;i--){
        int r = Random.Range(0,i);
        T tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[r];
        arr[r] = tmp;
    }
}

private IEnumerator LoadImages ()
{
    //load all images in default folder as textures and apply dynamically to plane game objects.
    ShuffleArray(files);
    textList = new Texture2D[files.Length];

    int dummy = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < gameObj.Length;i++) {
        string pathTemp = pathPreFix + files[i];
        WWW www = new WWW (pathTemp);
        yield return www;
        Texture2D texTmp = new Texture2D (1024, 1024, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);  
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture (texTmp);

        textList [dummy] = texTmp;

        gameObj[dummy].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texTmp;

        dummy++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Asset loading is best done early on.   If you do so when your game is loading, then all you have to do is call the collection that contains the assets and you won't have to deal with HDD read speeds. If you have way too many textures and this causes OutOfMemoryExceptions, consider low-resolution placeholders that you call first and call the high-rez images on a separate thread (Level of Detail, basically).

Comment: But you are suppose to call LoadImages  once in the Start function. Why are you calling it again from the FixedUpdate function?

Comment: Because I want the images to refresh with new ones.

Comment: Remove your FixedUpdate code for a start, it's not doing anything useful. Yield in your coroutine to WaitForSeconds(refresh). Use a List and amend it rather than building a new array each time in LoadImages to avoid the GC. Also, why build a new image from file with Texture2D texTmp = new Texture2D, why not pool all the images at start up and pick one randomly in your coroutine?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies I fixed the problem by splitting the `LoadImages()` method in two and doing the texture loading only once and then just shuffling the textures and then setting them to the game objects every ten seconds like was suggested.

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PhotoViewer : MonoBehaviour

{

GameObject[] gameObj;
Texture2D[] textList;

string[] files;
string[] filesShort;
string pathPreFix;
public float refresh = 10.0f;
public float targetTime = 10.0f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    //Debug.Log (targetTime);
    //Change this to change pictures folder
    //Debug.Log(Application.dataPath);

    string path = @"" + Application.dataPath + "/Images";

    pathPreFix = @"file://";

    gameObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Pics");

    files = new string[gameObj.Length];

    files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (path, "*.jpg");
    //files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (path, "*.png");
    //ShuffleArray(files);

    Debug.Log (files [1]);

    StartCoroutine (TextureStuff());
    Debug.Log ("Texture stuff done");
    LoadImages ();

    //StartCoroutine (LoadImages ());
    //LoadImages ();
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    //Debug.Log (targetTime);
    targetTime -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    if (targetTime <= 0.0f)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Update!");
        targetTime = refresh;
        //StartCoroutine (LoadImages ());
        LoadImages ();
        //Start();
    }
}

public static void ShuffleArray<T>(T[] arr){
    Debug.Log ("In Shuffle");
    for(int i = arr.Length - 1; i > 0;i--){
        int r = Random.Range(0,i);
        T tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[r];
        arr[r] = tmp;
    }
}

private void LoadImages ()
{
    //load all images in default folder as textures and apply dynamically to plane game objects.
    ShuffleArray(textList);

    int dummy = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < gameObj.Length;i++) {

        gameObj[i].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = textList [dummy];

        dummy++;
    }

}
private IEnumerator TextureStuff(){
    Debug.Log("In texture");
    textList = new Texture2D[files.Length];

    int dummy = 0;
    Debug.Log(gameObj.Length);
    for(int i = 0; i < gameObj.Length;i++) {
        string pathTemp = pathPreFix + files[i];
        Debug.Log (pathTemp);
        WWW www = new WWW (pathTemp);
        yield return www;
        Texture2D texTmp = new Texture2D (1024, 1024, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);  
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture (texTmp);

        textList [dummy] = texTmp;

        //gameObj[i].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texTmp;

        dummy++;
    }

}

}
```